# Solr dismax query

Tags: lucene, solr

I am trying to create a feature that allows search results to be displayed by this formula `sum(weight1*text relevance score, weight2 * price)`. `weight1` and `weight2` are numeric values that can be changed to influence the search results.

I am sending the following query params to the Solr instance for searching.

```
q=red
defType=dismax
qf=10^name+2^price
```

My understanding is that when using dismax, Solr/Lucene looks for the search text in all the fields specified in the `qf` param.

Currently my search results are similar to those I get when `qf` does not including a price. I think this is because price is a numeric field and there is not text match.

Is it possible to rank search results based on this formula - `sum(weight1*text relevance score, weight2 * price)`.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there! The syntax of qf is `qf=field^weight` and not the other way around.

See [this document](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2010/05/23/whats-a-dismax/) for more details.